# How to make Apache use only one IP (without using a firewall)?

Tags: apache-2.2, ip

I have a server with several static IPs (127.0.0.1,  127.0.0.2, etc.). I'd like to make Apache only listen on the 127.0.0.1 IP address for every domain (virtualhosts).

I tried the following:

```
# No NameVirtualHost used
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost one.domain.com>
...
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost two.domain.com>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

This didn't work as wanted as every virtualhost entry (and the IP) were pointing to the first VirtualHost entry.

Now I am using:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 80


<VirtualHost one.domain.com>
...
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost two.domain.com>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

But now Apache listens on every IP from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first setup was correct in concept, wrong in implementation.

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName one.domain.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName two.domain.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That's the solution, thanks. I also have to add that ServerName also needs to be set globally, otherwise Apache won't start, as happened with me.